# Saving new file and repeat each time the program is run?

Tags: python-3.x, file, operating-system

So I am trying to write my own program if you can even call it that. I am using pyautogui, time and os modules atm and all is dandy. The problem I am facing is I am opening notepad, pasting my content and trying to save it as a new file each time it's run.

I could use pyautogui to find where to go and click but think I can save myself the trouble and just paste the content from the web into the text file and save it, repeating each time the script is run.

I got up to the following:

```
os.system('start notepad.exe') 
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.hotkey(['ctrl', 'v'])
pyautogui.hotkey(['ctrl', 's'])
```

What I think I could do is:

```
file = open('Overload.txt', 'x')
pyautogui.hotkey(['ctrl', 'v'])
pyautogui.hotkey(['ctrl', 'v'])
```

I know I have to put either a for or while loop I think before either one but don't know where I am suppose to add a function where it runs again without overwriting the old text but saving a new text file like a backup with the same name, e.g., Overload(1).txt and have it dated.

TLDR: Trying to make backup files of text from the web that repeat the same filename but don't replace it. Sort like file logs.

I Googlfu this question and read through some but either were in different languages, I have just started learning or just mention the basic's of x,w,r,a+ which I don't need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
pyautogui.click(txtBox)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

time.sleep(5)

filename = "Overload.txt"
counter = 1

while os.path.exists(filename):
    filename = f"Overload.{counter}.txt"
    counter += 1

with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as newfile:
    newfile.write(pyperclip.paste())
```

Comment: Sorry I did not comment the code, if you don't understand it and or have question. Please let me know or ask.